# How to change the background color of an indented list item on hover using CSS?

Tags: css, string, list, hover, text-indent

I have an HTML list and each list item of LTR text has a hanging indent.  When the user hovers over a list item, I want the background of the entire string of the list item to be hovered.

But because of the hanging indent, the entire string does not get highlighted.

Here is a minimum reproducible code example of this issue:

```css
.test {
  margin-left: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  text-indent: -2em;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.test:hover {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<li class="test">hello world this is a test</li>
```

How can CSS be used to highlight the entire string on hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a pseudo element to cover the outside part:

```css
.test {
  margin-left: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  text-indent: -2em;
  list-style-type: none;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.test:hover {
  background: lime;
}
.test:hover::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:100%;
  width:2em;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<li class="test">hello world this is a test</li>
```

Like below to cover only the first line:

```css
.test {
  margin-left: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  text-indent: -2em;
  list-style-type: none;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.test:hover {
  background: lime;
}
.test:hover::before {
  content:"\200B"; /* an invisible character to define the height */
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  right:100%;
  width:2em;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<li class="test">hello world this is a test</li>
```

Comment: *Very* interesting! Thank you! I'm glad it wasn't something super obvious (well, maybe it was for you).  I'm going to give it a try in my code now to see if it works in context.  BTW, in SO's inline snippet boxes, the serifs on the left edge of the letter "h" in "hello" do not get the background color on hover (the background color is 1-2px too far to the right), but when I use the SO snippet full-page mode, they do.  Why is that happening??  I'm guessing it's a little browser rendering bug, but maybe you have more insight.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket yes probably a rendring bug. Increase the width a little to make sure you have enough space to cover the whole letter

Comment: Done! Everything works perfectly. Thank you! I'm trying to learn from your examples, and everything is really clear to me except the `top`, `bottom`, and `right` declarations.  If you have a few minutes, can you add to your answer (or here in the comments) why those 3 declarations are necessary?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket since it's a positionned element we need to place it correctly. `right:100%` will move it from the right side of the parent by 100% of the parent width so it will be outside from the left side (its right edge at the left side). `top:0` to start from the top of the parent. `bottom:0` (or `height:100%`) to cover all the parent height. In the second example I used a character to define te height so no need for bottom or height

Comment: Ah! I'm seeing it now. Thank you, as always, so much.  Maybe when CSS finally supports the proposed `hanging` value (see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) for the `text-indent` property, this will no longer be needed. But until then, this works great, and now it makes perfect sense in my head.  Thank you again Temani.